Spring Shell not running interactive mode windows 11 - Unable to create a system terminal, creating a dumb terminal
I'have created simple SpringShell app (java 21 and maven) using spring initializr and created class HelloCommand.java.
While running app in IntelliJ IDEA I'm occurring a warning Unable to create a system terminal, creating a dumb terminal (enable debug logging for more information). If I build a .jar file and try to run in in windows 11 terminal problem still occur. From the other hand in WSL Ubuntu it doesn't show an error, but interactive mode is still not working.
This is my Main class
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.shell.standard.ShellComponent;

@SpringBootApplication
public class demoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(demoApplication.class, args);
    }

And this is HelloCommand.java class
package com.example.demo.commands;

import org.springframework.shell.standard.ShellComponent;
import org.springframework.shell.standard.ShellMethod;

@ShellComponent
public class HelloCommand {

    @ShellMethod(key = "hello", value = "I will say hello")
    public String hello(){
        return "Hello world!";
    }
}

If I run app in non interactive mod with java -jar demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar hello message is printed correctly
I have tried adding dependency
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.fusesource.jansi</groupId>
            <artifactId>jansi</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version>
        </dependency>

to handle ansii escape keys, but it didnt help

As the other solution said, spring shell 3.3.x requires to enable the interactive mode in application.properties
spring.shell.interactive.enabled=true
spring.shell.script.enabled=true

Hint for Gradle Users
You may need additionaly add to build.gradle the following:
bootRun {
    standardInput = System.in
}

Its the fix then the shell directly closed like this:
> Task :bootRun

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/

 :: Spring Boot ::                (v3.3.2)
2024-08-11T22:28:23.345+02:00  INFO 10524 --- [demo] [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : Started DemoApplication in 1.151 seconds
shell:>
BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 2s
4 actionable tasks: 4 executed


The official documentation doesn't include this.
Add this property
spring.shell.interactive.enabled=true


For me only after adding both configurations resolved the problem:
spring.shell.interactive.enabled=true
spring.shell.script.enabled=true

